# Differences between replaced inline elements and inline-block elements

Tags: html, block, inline, css

Could I get a few concrete examples of how these two differ? It seems that replaced inline elements have properties like `width`, `height`, `margin` etc that non-replaced inline elements don't have (thus making the difference between block elements and replaced inline elements harder to explain) and vice versa, inline-blocks have some of the delicate features that inline elements have as well...

They sorta meet in the middle it seems coming from two different ends...

Comment: replaced? If an element has `inline` it will be display `inline, if it has `inline-block` it will be an `inline-block` element...

Comment: yes but replaced inline elements and non-replaced behave differently to a certain extent...

Comment: Could you give examples, maybe a jsfiddle.net? My understanding is that there is no difference. Still, check it out with an inspector and see for yourself i guess.

Comment: I think the key difference is that replaced inline elements have intrinsic dimensions and some of these can't be fully styled via css (e.g. a form input)

Comment: @Fabrizio Calderan: that's definately a difference I didn't think of, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this fiddle will give you a better insight in `inline`, `inline-block` and `block`

http://jsfiddle.net/4h9JS/

The biggest difference is that `inline-block` is still an inline element, but **behaves** as a block element

Comment: Thanks but this example doesn't even contain a replaced inline element